# ReactJS Warning: Encountered two children with the same key after changing components

Tags: reactjs

I created a reactJS app that has a main page and a details page, the main page get data from a database that has a alpha numeric unique key, once i click the details page and render the details component but when i go back to the main page `Warning : Encountered two children with the same key` is encountered.

This key is from a firebase database.

My App.js

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
       <Router>
        <Navbar />
        <Route  path="/" exact component={ExpenseList} />
        <Route  path="/details/:id"   component={ExpenseDetails} />
       </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

My main page component the tran variable is set as a global variable

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { Link, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import {db} from '../server';
let tran = [];

componentDidMount(){
        db.collection('transactions').orderBy('added_at', 'desc').onSnapshot(snapshot => {
        let changes = snapshot.docChanges();
         changes.forEach(change => {
            if(change.type == 'added'){
         
               tran.push(change.doc);
        
                } 
            });   
          this.setState( {transactions: tran});    
                });
    }

  displayTransactions(){
    return this.state.transactions.map(transaction => {
        return <Transaction record={transaction.data()}  key={transaction.id} sequence={transaction.id} />;
        
    })
}

   render(){
      return(
        <div className="container mt-4">
            <h2>Transaction List</h2>

            <div className="mt-5" id="renderTransactions">
                {this.displayTransactions()}
            </div>

        </div>
       
    )
}
```

My details page

```
componentDidMount(){
        var docID = this.props.match.params.id;
        db.collection('transactions').doc(docID).get().then( doc => {

            let details = {
                 _id: doc.id,
                 title: doc.data().title,
                 details: doc.data().details,
                 category: doc.data().category,
                 dateTransaction: doc.data().dateTransaction,
                 amount: doc.data().amount,
                 transType: doc.data().transType,
              }

              this.setState( {transactionDetails: details});
        });
    }

transactionDetails(){
           return <TransactionDetails record={this.state.transactionDetails} deleteTransaction={this.deleteTransaction} />;     
    }

 render(){

    return(
      <div className="mt-5">
            
            <div className="container">
              <h2 className="mb-5">Transaction Details</h2>
              {this.transactionDetails()} 
            </div>
       </div>
      
      )
    
}
```

Comment: can you add the `render` function of the detail page

Comment: Where are you mapping your data and using React keys? Please include a full example. What is `tran`? Where is it declared? You appear to be mutating it whatever it is.

Comment: Yeah, it definitely appears you are mutating state. Can you clarify what `change.type == 'added'` does? If the component remounts and that same db query is invoked, are different data elements returned?

Comment: @DrewReese fthe change.type checks if the firebase database is equals to added, every time there's a new data in firebase this will execute, the same data elements will be returned including the new added data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

Ok, so it seems you are mutating state, indirectly. `tran` caches all previously fetched db data.

```
let tran = [];

componentDidMount(){
  db.collection('transactions').orderBy('added_at', 'desc').onSnapshot(snapshot => {
    let changes = snapshot.docChanges();
    changes.forEach(change => {
      if(change.type == 'added'){
         tran.push(change.doc);
      } 
    });   
    this.setState({ transactions: tran });    
  });
}
```

`tran` appears to be locally global, and each time the component mounts it pushes all the changes into `tran` and then sets state. Each time the component mounts, it again pushes all the changes into `tran` and sets state. These subsequent mountings use the existing populated `tran` array and possibly pushes in duplicate data.

## Solution

I suspect you meant for each mount to be "fresh". For this I suggest mapping the `changes` to your state. Since the "same data elements will be returned including the new added data" you can simply consume the entire array, there is no need to keep "state" outside the component and no need to filter by the "added" elements.

```
componentDidMount(){
  db.collection('transactions').orderBy('added_at', 'desc').onSnapshot(snapshot => {
    const changes = snapshot.docChanges();
    this.setState({ transactions: changes });    
  });
}
```